# AngularAMD fails to load Modules with Dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, restangular

I try to load a module that has dependencies to 'restangular'. But if I try to use the 'RestangularProvider' in the loaded modules config it gives the following errror:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RestangularProviderProvider <- RestangularProvider
```

This is the "main" module that loads the other module dynamically when the route "/app" is matched:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angularUiRouter', 'restangular'], function (angularAMD) {
var module = angular.module(
    'Index', [
        'ui.router',
        'restangular'
    ])
    .config([
        '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'RestangularProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app");
            $stateProvider
                .state('app', angularAMD.route({
                    url: '/app',
                    templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
                    controller: 'AppController',
                    controllerUrl: 'ngload!app'
                }));
            RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
        }])
    .run([
        function run() {
        }])
    .controller(
    'IndexController',
    [
        '$scope', '$rootScope', '$location',
        function controller($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
        }
    ]);
angularAMD.bootstrap(module);
return module;
});
```

And this is the app module that gets loaded:

```
define([], function () {
var module = angular.module(
    'App', [
        'ui.router',
        'restangular'
    ])
    .config([
        'RestangularProvider',
        function (RestangularProvider) {
        }])
    .controller(
        'AppController',
        [
            '$scope', '$rootScope', '$location',
            function controller($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
                $scope.message = "App";
            }
        ]);
return module;
});
```

Without the 'RestangularProvider' in the config the app works fine.

But with the 'RestangularProvider' or any other provider I tested it doesn't.

It seems that it is not possible for modules loaded by AngularAMD to have any other dependencies.

To be clear, the module loads, but the dependencies seem to be unavailable in the loaded modules config.

What can I do?

PS: This is the requirejs config:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "",
paths: {
    'lodash': 'Vendor/lodash/lodash',
    'jquery': 'Vendor/jquery/jquery-1.10.2',
    'angular': 'Vendor/angular/angular-1.2.3',
    'angularAMD': 'Vendor/angular-amd/angularAMD',
    'angularRoute': 'Vendor/angular/angular-route',
    'angularUiRouter': 'Vendor/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router',
    'ngload': 'Vendor/angular-amd/ngload',
    'restangular': 'Vendor/restangular/restangular',
    'app': 'app/app'
},
shim: {
    'angular': ['jquery'],
    'angularAMD': ['angular'],
    'ngload': ['angularAMD'],
    'angularRoute': ['angular'],
    'angularUiRouter': ['angular'],
    'restangular': ['angular', 'lodash'],
    'app': ['angularUiRouter', 'restangular']
},
deps: ['Index']
```

});

Comment: Is this still an issue?  The problem seems to be a combination of use of 'deps: ['Index']` and files you call "main" and "app".  Is there a way for me to see the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that does not look right in your config/code:

1. Your "main" module should really be the "app.js" module.
2. I am not clear what is your "app" module is doing.  The config of restangular should take place in the proper "app.js" module.
3. In your "requirejs config", you are referencing `deps: ['Index']` which doesn't really exists.  You should be refering the "app.js" module instead.

Here is a working plunker demonstration how you can lozay load Restangular using [angularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/):
http://plnkr.co/edit/zXRuFwoncXZux1TgVUCM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into similar issues recently.  What worked best for me was to include the "exports" in the shim, instead of just the "deps".  When you include an "exports" (no matter the # of deps defined), requirejs will make sure those dependencies are loaded for that module.  Does this make sense?

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",
    paths: {
        'lodash': 'Vendor/lodash/lodash',
        'jquery': 'Vendor/jquery/jquery-1.10.2',
        'angular': 'Vendor/angular/angular-1.2.3',
        'angularAMD': 'Vendor/angular-amd/angularAMD',
        'angularRoute': 'Vendor/angular/angular-route',
        'angularUiRouter': 'Vendor/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router',
        'ngload': 'Vendor/angular-amd/ngload',
        'restangular': 'Vendor/restangular/restangular',
        'app': 'app/app'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularAMD': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularAMD'
        },
        'ngload': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'ngload'
        },
        'angularRoute':{
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularRoute'
        },
        'angularUiRouter': 
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularUiRouter'
        },
        'restangular': {
            deps: ['angular','lodash'],
            exports: 'restangular'
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['angular','angularAMD','angularUiRouter', 'restangular'],
            exports: 'app'
        }
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

I'm confused with what "Index" is and why you have two similar modules defined; the first should suffice. You should only have to call the app.js as the main deps in your require config. This basically tells requirejs to immediately make that module available. Read this carefully http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim